# Dask-Rapids data movment and out of memory issue

Tags: dask-distributed, cupy, rapids, dask-ml

I am using dask (2021.3.0) and rapids(0.18) in my project. In this, I am performing preprocessing task on the CPU, and later the preprocessed data is transferred to GPU for K-means clustering. But in this process, I am getting the following problem:

1 of 1 worker jobs failed: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error: ~/envs/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp:69: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory
(before using GPU memory completely it gave the error i.e. it is not using GPU memory completely)

I  have a single GPU of size 40 GB.
Ram size 512 GB.

I am using following snippet of code:

```
cluster=LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=1)
cluster.scale(100)
##perform my preprocessing on data and get output on variable A
# convert A varible to cupy
x = A.map_blocks(cp.asarray)
km =KMeans(n_clusters=4)
predict=km.fit_predict(x).compute()
```

I am also looking for a solution so that the data larger than GPU memory can be preprocessed, and whenever there is a spill in GPU memory the spilled data is transferred into temp directory or CPU (as we do with dask where we define temp directory when there is a spill in RAM).

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to run larger than GPU datasets.

1. Check out [Nick Becker's blog](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/reading-larger-than-memory-csvs-with-rapids-and-dask-e6e27dfa6c0f), which has a few methods well documented
2. Check out [BlazingSQL](https://blazingsql.com), which is built on top of RAPIDS and can perform out of core processings.  You can try it at beta.blazingsql.com.

Comment: Dear TaureanDyerNV,
Thank you for your kind attention to my problem.
However, I am using CPU-based preprocessing on the inputted dataset by first creating LocalCluster, and then transfer data to GPU, which can be controlled via LocalCudaCluster. In this situation,  I am wondering how to transfer data from LocalCluster to LocalCudaCluster.

In my code snippet, I directly transfer my data from LocalCluster to GPU without making LocalCudaCluster.

Could you please help me in this regard also, as I am not getting any solution for this.